# How to split string in a specific order using Google Apps Script?

Tags: regex, string, google-apps-script, formatting

I am new with Google apps script and trying to learn day by day. I apologize for my basic knowledge. I am trying to split a string in a specific way. Here is the string in an array:

> **var** **data** = [call number="7203266298" duration="0" date="1646769239639" type="2"
> presentation="1" subscription_id="89148000007344410028"
> post_dial_digits=""
> subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService"
> readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)"]

Now I want to split this text in the following format:

```
var data = [call number="7203266298",
duration="0",
date="1646769239639",
type="2",
presentation="1", 
subscription_id="89148000007344410028",
subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService",
readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM", 
contact_name="(Unknown)"]
```

I tried to use `split()` function like this:

```
data = data.split(" ")
```

But the output from this method is not really what I need, it creates unnecessary partitions like this:

> [ , , call, number="+12532250046", duration="0", date="1646851016349",
> type="3", presentation="1", subscription_id="89148000007344410028",
> post_dial_digits="",
> subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService",
> readable_date="**Mar**, **9**,, **2022**, **11:36:56**, **AM**", contact_name="(Unknown)",
> ]

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Regex in apps script works the same way it does in JavaScript, take a look at docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and test your cases: https://regexr.com/

Comment: thank you for the link, but due to my poor skills I could not get my desired output, that's why I need help

Comment: Is that the exact way that the string is supposed to look like? Where is it coming from? It looks like it's some kind of Java map turned into a String, but there are a couple of inconsistencies like `call number` instead of `call_number` and a missing comma after the date string before `contact_name`. I'm not sure if that's a typo. I'm asking because it would be easier to create a regex for it if it's actually consistent.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for your reply, the below answer works fine without regex.

Comment: That's good. I was already working on a solution with a regex so I posted it anyway as an alternative in case that you also need to work with similar strings of different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this could be to combine array indexes in new array that you want to see in combination. For example:

```
var temp = [call number="7203266298" duration="0" date="1646769239639" type="2" presentation="1" subscription_id="89148000007344410028" post_dial_digits="" subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService" readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)"];
temp = temp.split(" ");

newData = [temp[0]+" "+temp[1], temp[2],temp[3],temp[4],temp[5],temp[6], temp[7],temp[8],temp[9]+" "+temp[10]+" "+temp[11]+" "+temp[12]+" "+temp[13], 
temp[14]];

Logger.log(newData);

Output:

[call number="7203266298", duration="0", date="1646769239639", type="2", presentation="1", subscription_id="89148000007344410028", post_dial_digits="", subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService", readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM", contact_name="(Unknown)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using a simple regex that should work for any amount of elements and also if the order changes:

```
function myFunction() {

  var data = '[call number="7203266298" duration="0" date="1646769239639" type="2" presentation="1" subscription_id="89148000007344410028" post_dial_digits="" subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService" readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)"]'

  var re = new RegExp('"(.*?)"', "g") // finds sequences enclosed in quotes ""

  data = data.slice(1,-1) //removes the [] for a cleaner look if necessary
  
  var values = data.match(re)
  var indexes = data.replace(re, "/-/").split("/-/").slice(0, -1)

  var output = []

  for (i=0; i< indexes.length;i++){
    output.push(indexes[i].trim()+values[i])
  }

  console.log(output)
}
```

Output:

```
[ 'call number="7203266298"',
  'duration="0"',
  'date="1646769239639"',
  'type="2"',
  'presentation="1"',
  'subscription_id="89148000007344410028"',
  'post_dial_digits=""',
  'subscription_component_name="com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService"',
  'readable_date="Mar 8, 2022 12:53:59 PM"',
  'contact_name="(Unknown)"' ]
```

The way it works is that it finds all the `"values"`, puts them in an array, and replaces them with a unique separator `"/-/"`, then it splits the indexes using that separator and then builds a new `output` array joining the array of indexes with the array of values.

Comment: However there is only one element in this array. If the length  of this array increases (e.g 230) in an array then script crashes. Can you propose anything for that? thank you

Comment: What does this longer string look like? Is it multiple arrays like the original one but joined together?

Comment: the array `data` you used in your answer has one index, same strings will be on other indexes also